# Flutter app ANR bad behavior in Play Store

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, anr

I have a Flutter app in Google Play Store.
I have recently crossed the bad behavior threshold for ANRs, but reports make no sense!

The main report shows frequent ANRs and a rate of .6%
[image: User Perceived ANR Rate]

When I drill into "View Issues" I get this report which shows only a single issue 17 days ago for a fairly old app version 323 (current one is 350).

[image: View Issues]

When I drill into "View Metric", I get the same graph but different app versions: 341 and 346.
[image: View Metric]

When I drill into app version 346, I get a flat line with no ANRs at all!?
[image: ANR rate for app version 346]

These reports seem to contradict each other. Does anyone know how to interpret these and what could I do about this?